# Visual Studio 2013 VmWare Remote Debugging failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm trying to get the remote debugging in Visual Studio work. I have VmWare 11 installed which gave me the plugin for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, that i'm using. I did setup the Virtual Debugger Configuration like so:

```
Virtual Machine: path to my vmx

Remote Debugger Monitor Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe"

Remote Debug Monitor Name: "SUPERPC"

Guest Command: <Use host's Visual Studio project command>

Shared folders: <empty>

Guest Login Credentials : user=myuser, password=mypassword
```

My VmWare is running windows 8 with PC named "SUPERPC", and my os is windows 7. So i press "attach to process" in VmWare Visual Studio toolbar, select my virtual machine, and successfully get the processes list. I then choose my app from the list and click attach, the studio hangs for a few seconds and then:

[image: error]

this pop's up.

Visual studio console says:

```
Debugging started...
Starting the virtual machine.
Waiting for VMware Tools to start...
VMware Tools has started.
Waiting for login to complete...
An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
Login succeeded.
Enabling shared folders succeeded
Sharing Command directory: 
  U:\project\VkMonitor\debug\ as .VkMonitor6508
Adding share folder succeeded.
Checking for running Remote Debug Monitor in the virtual machine.
Sharing Remote Debug Monitor directory:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\ as .RemoteDebugMonitor24083
Enabling shared folders succeeded
Adding share folder succeeded.
Starting the Remote Debug Monitor: \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\.RemoteDebugMonitor24083\msvsmon.exe /nowowwarn /port 4015
Preparing the project's configuration properties for live debugging.
An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
Debugging Failed.
The Remote Debug Monitor running in the virtual machine has been stopped. Process ID: 1900.
Removing Command share: .VkMonitor6508.
Removing share folder succeeded
Removing Remote Debug Monitor share: .RemoteDebugMonitor24083.
Removing share folder succeeded
```

I checked the log file in `C:\Users\pcuser\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware-pcuser`

```
11.08.2015 2:41:50: Attaching to process started...
11.08.2015 2:41:50: Checking for running Remote Debug Monitor in the virtual machine.
11.08.2015 2:41:57: Sharing Remote Debug Monitor directory:
11.08.2015 2:41:57:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\ as .RemoteDebugMonitor13246
11.08.2015 2:41:57: Enabling shared folders succeeded
11.08.2015 2:41:57: Adding share folder succeeded.
11.08.2015 2:41:57: Starting the Remote Debug Monitor: \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\.RemoteDebugMonitor13246\msvsmon.exe /nowowwarn /port 4015
11.08.2015 2:44:27: Failed to attach the debugger to selected processes.
11.08.2015 2:44:27: Failed to stop the Remote Debug Monitor running in the virtual machine. Process ID: 2816. Authentication failure or insufficient permissions in guest operating system.
11.08.2015 2:44:27: Removing Remote Debug Monitor share: .RemoteDebugMonitor13246.
11.08.2015 2:44:27: Removing share folder succeeded
```

Is there something specific need to be done to make this work, or is this even possible with windows 8?

And also in my virtual machine i can see that Visual Studio Remote Monitor has started successfuly with message:

```
"Msvsmon started a new server named 'SUPERPC:4015'. Waiting for new connections"
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to do the connection without authentication, i manually ran msvsmon and disabled authentication. The result was the same but the produced log was:

```
11.08.2015 3:55:48: Attaching to process started...
11.08.2015 3:55:48: Checking for running Remote Debug Monitor in the virtual machine.
11.08.2015 3:56:04: An instance of the Remote Debug Monitor already running in the virtual machine will be used for this debug session.
11.08.2015 3:56:26: Failed to attach the debugger to selected processes.
11.08.2015 3:56:26: ERROR: StopMonitor(pAttachData->m_handle, pAttachData->m_monitorProcId)
11.08.2015 3:56:26: An error occurred in .\attachDlg.cpp at line 456. Error code is 0x1.
11.08.2015 3:56:26: ERROR: UnshareMonitorFolder(pAttachData->m_handle, pAttachData->m_monitorShare)
11.08.2015 3:56:26: An error occurred in .\attachDlg.cpp at line 458. Error code is 0x1.
```

Also i tried to RUN the process instead of attaching to it. This fails too and produces the log like this:

```
11.08.2015 4:01:07: Getting the list of running virtual machines on the host...
11.08.2015 4:01:07: Virtual machine found powered on: Windows 8 x64.
11.08.2015 4:01:09: VMware Tools has started.
11.08.2015 4:01:09: Login succeeded.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: Debugging started...
11.08.2015 4:01:24: Starting the virtual machine.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: Waiting for VMware Tools to start...
11.08.2015 4:01:24: ERROR: pControls->get_Item(CComVariant(itemName), &pCtrl)
11.08.2015 4:01:24: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 8782. Error code is 0x80070057.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: ERROR: pControls->get_Item(CComVariant(itemName), &pCtrl)
11.08.2015 4:01:24: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 8782. Error code is 0x80070057.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: VMware Tools has started.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: Waiting for login to complete...
11.08.2015 4:01:24: Login succeeded.
11.08.2015 4:01:24: Enabling shared folders succeeded
11.08.2015 4:01:24: Sharing Command directory: 
11.08.2015 4:01:24:   U:\project\VkMonitor\debug\ as .VkMonitor16077
11.08.2015 4:01:25: Adding share folder succeeded.
11.08.2015 4:01:25: Checking for running Remote Debug Monitor in the virtual machine.
11.08.2015 4:01:35: An instance of the Remote Debug Monitor already running in the virtual machine will be used for this debug session.
11.08.2015 4:01:35: Preparing the project's configuration properties for live debugging.
11.08.2015 4:01:35: ERROR: pControls->get_Item(CComVariant(itemName), &pCtrl)
11.08.2015 4:01:35: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 8782. Error code is 0x80070057.
11.08.2015 4:01:35: An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
11.08.2015 4:01:35: ERROR: pControls->get_Item(CComVariant(itemName), &pCtrl)
11.08.2015 4:01:35: An error occurred in .\Connect.cpp at line 8782. Error code is 0x80070057.
11.08.2015 4:01:35: An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
11.08.2015 4:01:38: Debugger->Go failed with error 0x80004005.
11.08.2015 4:01:42: Debugger->Go failed with error 0x80004005.
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the dialog that popped up?

Comment: About this dialog first point: My user and password in vmware operating system are not the same as my user and password on my OS. Is this allright or i suppose to have the same?

Comment: @IInspectable also i turned off windows 8 firewall on my VMWare, and remote debug monitor name in the configuration match the PC name of my Vmware system  - "SUPERPC". And this name is unique

Comment: Since the dialog specifically states, that you have to be logged into the guest and host OS using the same credentials, I'm pretty sure that it is not ok to be logged into the guest and host OS using different credentials.

Comment: @IInspectable i just tried to do that. I created another user with the same name and password as mine in Virtual Machine Os. I changed the credentials in the debugger configruation i got the same effect. And the log:   http://pastebin.com/K2yEvvTv

Comment: @IInspectable for some reason the visual studio states that it fails to access the list of running processes in vmware as shown in my screen, but when you attach to process you already have the list of the processess retrieved..

Comment: *"... on the same domain"*

Comment: @IInspectable ok at the moment both users are in workgroups so i need to setup the domain controller on both operating system and then assign both users to the same domain name?

Comment: @IInspectable nvm actually, i tried to do this with disabled authentication just right now, the result is the same

Comment: @IInspectable vmware remote debugger with disabled authentication produce this log http://pastebin.com/ywyEuNFg